# Floating container overlaps bottom div, but not top

Tags: css, html, positioning

Hey i'm a little unsure about this structure.
Essentially I want to a have 4 divs.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-border"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="bottom-border"></div>
</div>
```

The container holds the three smaller divs. My goal is to have the box div hold the content, and the border divs create a bracket around the box. Border-top will be floated to the left, and border-bottom will be floated to the right. The only issue is that the container overlaps the bottom bracket, but not the top. I don't want it to overlap either... Is there a way to fix this?

Here is a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ghzN/

Answer (score 5):

On the bottom-border div, change

```
margin-top: -40px;
```

to

```
margin-bottom: -8px;
```

Comment: That worked nicely thanks! I wasn't aware margin-top and margin-bottom would act differently in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I would go a different way,

Just add `.box:before` and `.box:after`

This way, you don't have all those extra divs to be marked up!

```
.container{
    background:#dedede;
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
.box{
    height:800px;
    width:100%;
    color:#cecece;
    float:left; 
    position:relative;
}
.box:before{
    content: "";
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-left: 8px solid gray;
    border-top: 8px solid gray;
    position: absolute;
    left: -8px;
    top: -8px;
}
.box:after{
    content: "";
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-right: 8px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 8px solid gray;
    position: absolute;
    right: -8px;
    bottom: -8px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ghzN/11/

Comment: Please note that `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes are not supported in IE7-. http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent

Comment: I really like this solution, but unfortunately the CMS i'm using doesn't currently support pseudo-classes. Definitely will keep it in mind down the road!

Answer (score 1):

I had success using this method:

1) Remove background color from `.container` and add it to `.box`.

```
.box{
    ...
    background:#dedede;   
}
```

2) Add a negative margin to the right of `.top-border` so that `.box` floats correctly:

```
.top-border{
    ...
    margin-right:-40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ghzN/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-bottom: -10px;` to bottom-border class.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ghzN/10/)